# Ctrl + T to show class

Tags: resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2012

With resharper we can click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

This brings up the class so you can click to view the class.

Is there a similar shortcut available/ built in visual studio 2012 (express)?

**Note: I am talking about not having resharper installed**

Answer (score 21):

Go to the menu Tools->Options. There under Environment->Keyboard. In the list there you need the entry ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoType. Select this and then go to the textbox and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 19):

When selecting a class in the Text Editor you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> to navigate to the class.

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to search for Classes (and fields, properties etc).

To inspect the keyboard mappings you can open (menu):

**Tools** >> **Options** then select **Environment** >> **Keyboard**. There you can find commands and their binding.

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx) has a list of pre-defined keyboard shortcuts.

[DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx) has a list of mapped command.

Comment: When selecting a class is fine, I am talking about a quick search for classes like resharper does

Comment: It should, maybe ReSharper screwed things up... Can you locate it by using the menu 'Edit > Navigate To'?. When you do, there should be a shortcut mentioned there.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
That's how I use it. You can use it this way